# How to assign values in arrays according to a specific sequence

Tags: python, numpy

I try to assign a value from the second matrix to each value from the first matrix according to the procedure.
I assign a value to each value in the first row, then to each value in the last column. Then I assign a value in the second row, just like in the penultimate column, but the first and last values from the second matrix are omitted. That is, and until each value from the first matrix is assigned a value from the second matrix.

It is better to see this in the example below.
example

Input

```
a = np.array([[11,12,13],
              [21,22,23],
              [31,32,33],
              [41,42,43],
              [51,52,53]])

b= np.array([100,200,300,400,500,600,700])
```

required output

```
11 100
12 200
13 300
23 400
33 500
43 600
53 700
21 200
22 300
32 400
42 500
52 600

31 300
41 400
51 500
```

It is possible?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to reproduce your required output for the given input with the following code:

```
import numpy as np

def matrix_assing(a, b):
    output = []
    
    for i in range(len(a[0])):
        horizontal_values_to_assign = a[i][: len(a[i]) - i]
        vertical_values_to_assing = a.T[-(i+1)][i+1:]
        
        values_to_assign = np.append(horizontal_values_to_assign, vertical_values_to_assing)
        
        output += list(zip(values_to_assign, b[i:len(b) - i]))
        
    return output

a = np.array([[11,12,13],
              [21,22,23],
              [31,32,33],
              [41,42,43],
              [51,52,53]])

b = np.array([100,200,300,400,500,600,700])

matrix_assing(a, b)
```

Could you please be more specific what should happen when the length of b does not fit around the sides of the matrix a (`len(b) != len(a[0]) + len(a.T[0]) - 1`).

Comment: the formula is written so that it always fits the pages. but there will be no matrix of the same size as it is now. But they should a and b b should always be symmetric

Comment: As long as `b` fits around `a`, this function should deliver the wanted output.

Comment: I'll try it on multiple nuts and let me know if there is a problem, thanks for the help